# Convert django view to django rest framework APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to convert a django view to APIView, here's the normal view and below is what I tried.

**Django View**

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class QuizResultsView(DetailView):
    model = Quiz
    context_object_name = 'quiz'
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/quiz_results.html'

    def get_context_data (self, **kwargs):
        quiz = self.get_object()

        if (quiz.status == 'Assigned'):

            """Some Code"""

            cursor = connection.cursor()


            def dictfetchall (cursor):
                desc = cursor.description
                return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

            """ Some More Code """

            extra_context = {'taken_quizzes': taken_quizzes, 'total_taken_quizzes': total_taken_quizzes,
                             'quiz_score': quiz_score, 'least_bid': least_bid, 'matching_bids': matching_bids,
                             'driver_num': driver_num, 'lat_lon_orig': lat_lon_orig, 'lat_lon_dest': lat_lon_dest,
                             'user_pass': user_pass, 'username': username, 'password': password, }


            kwargs.update(extra_context)


            return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)


        else:

            cursor = connection.cursor()

            def dictfetchall (cursor):
                desc = cursor.description
                return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

            cursor.execute('''SELECT STATEMENT''', [quiz.id])

        """ Some More Code """


            extra_context = {'taken_quizzes': taken_quizzes, 'total_taken_quizzes': total_taken_quizzes,
                             'quiz_score': quiz_score, 'least_bid': least_bid, 'matching_bids': matching_bids}
            kwargs.update(extra_context)

            return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def get_queryset (self):
        return self.request.user.quizzes.all()
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) I added :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

in my settings.py and instead of `return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` i used `return Response(extra_content)` but it doesn't seem to work. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Please, help!!

Answer (score 0):

As the [**`documentation`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#api-policy-settings):

> The following settings control the basic API policies, and are applied to every APIView class-based view, or @api_view function based view.

Means, the changes you have done will be reflected in [**`APIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views) or subclass of`APIView`, not in `DetailView` or any django CBV.

You can simply convert your view to an `APIView` like this:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class QuizResultsView(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
          quiz = self.get_object(pk)
          # --- rest of the code ---
          return Response(extra_content)
```

But I would recommend using a [**`GenericView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) or [**`RetrieveAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview), and use [**`serializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to serialize data.